# Will this 301 redirect will work as intended?

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect, web-hosting, http-redirect

I wanted to redirect `olddomain.example` to the new-domain's category page, including all the other URLs from olddomain to this page: `https://new-domain.example/category-page/` using `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new-domain.example/category-page/ [L,R=301]
```

both websites are hosted on a different hosting providers.

I tried it but it only redirects the olddomain to the new-domain's category page. It doesn't redirect other URLs of olddomain.

Comment: I'd expect it to work.  How are you testing it?

Comment: I test using this website https://wheregoes.com/

Comment: Try testing with [curl](https://curl.se).  Use the `--head` argument to see the `Location:` header.

Comment: This works as described. You could even simplify the matching pattern, since you are not referring to anything matched: `RewriteRule ^ https://new-domain.example/category-page/ [L,R=301]`